# Short story about two Native American brothers who were chased down a mountain by a monster

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror

I’m looking for the name of a story about two Native American brothers who were in the woods on a mountain. There was a monster (I think it was a Bigfoot or a cyclops or something humanoid) that was chasing them down the mountain and it fought and ate one of the brothers. The part where he ate the brother was very descriptive.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: Could this be Algernon Blackwood's [*The Wendigo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wendigo_(novella))? It doesn't quite fit - only one person in the story is a native, the rest are back-woods men hired as guides by the narrator and they don't fight the Wendigo as such.